# .NET Communications Component

Tags: .net, networking, network-programming, components

I'm looking for a component for C#.NET 2008 Professional that is capable of doing the majority of the network communications work that is required of our application so our programmers don't have to.

This component should function similarly to the way [RealThinClient](http://www.realthinclient.org/) (RTC) does.  The component must be able to gracefully lose and regain connections.  It must have encryption built-in.  It must have compression built in.  RTC is capable of doing connection pooling as well and this is something that we would also like to have.

A little background about us: we were previously a Delphi 7 shop and are moving to using Visual Studio .NET 2008.  We just located RTC before we made the decision to move to .NET and are wishing that there was something that duplicated the functionality available.  :-)

Thanks for your help and links are much appreciated.

Michael Beck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF,

Windows Communication Foundation is a set of libraries in the .net framework 3.0 that abstracts application communication from your code.

All of your communications are abstracted so that you use your business objects as if there was no actual communication going on.

It also allows you to fully configure what types of communication protocols, security, etc. you want to use without you changing your code.

This may not be exactly what you are looking for, but WCF should always be considered when doing application communication in a .net system.

Start here 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/content/en-us/msft/netframework/wcf/GettingStarted

Answer (score 2):

You should look at IPWorks from www.NSoftware.com   Not only do they have a Dot Net library, they have a Delphi component as well.  This might help you convert.  If you buy their Red Carpet Subscription you'd get all libraries.